# bokeh CategoricalColorMapper generates repeated legends

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm using bokeh to draw squares of different categories.

The legend, however, is showing the same categories multiple times, one for each instance on the figure, instead of one time for each unique category.

Here is a minimal code to reproduce my problem:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CategoricalColorMapper

ranges = [range(0, 100),
          range(100, 200),
          range(200, 300)]

cols = ['blue',
        'lime',
        'yellow']

labels = ['low',
          'medium',
          'high']

ranges_dict = dict(zip(ranges, labels))

lat = [0, 0, 100, 100]
lon = [0, 100, 0, 100]
values = [1, 150, 150, 250]

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
        x=lon,
        y=lat,
        label=[[ranges_dict[r] for r in ranges if x in r] for x in values]
    ))

color_mapper = CategoricalColorMapper(factors=labels, palette=cols)

fig = figure(toolbar_location='below',
             width=500, height=400)

fig.rect(source=source,
         x='x', y='y',
         width=100,
         height=100,
         color={'field': 'label', 'transform': color_mapper},
         line_alpha=0.5, fill_alpha=0.5,
         legend='label'
         )

show(fig)
```

Notice that "medium" appears twice:
[image: bokeh output]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `[[ranges_dict[r] for r in ranges if x in r] for x in values]` returns a list of lists: 
`[['high'], ['medium'], ['low'], ['high']]`.

To transform it into a simple list, I used **numpy.hstack**, so the label argument for ColumnDataSource is on the form it should be:
`['high', 'medium', 'low', 'high']`